# Creating tag only if value exist in source

Tags: java, xslt

For example:

```
<a>
<b>
    <aaa>val</aaa>
    <bbb></bbb>
</b>
</a>
```

I want an xslt that will create aaa,bbb,ccc tags only if they contain value in source.

Until now i used:

```
<aaa><xsl:value-of select="//aaa"/></aaa>
<bbb><xsl:value-of select="//bbb"/></bbb>
<ccc><xsl:value-of select="//ccc"/></ccc>
```

Which is clearly not good.

Comment: An element name cannot start with a digit, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087108/encoding-xml-element-name-beginning-with-a-number

Comment: Ok this was example, i edited it to chars

Comment: XSLT stylesheets usually transform one XML to another XML. Please edit your question and show both your input XML and the output XML you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answers, this doesn't rely on names or structure; it simply strips elements that do not contain any child elements or text. Like it was previously mentioned, it is difficult to tell what output you're actually looking for.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*|text())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<a>
   <b>
      <aaa>val</aaa>
   </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions about what you'd like to achieve (you did not say it so clearly I'm afraid), the solutions below should work.

**Input**

```
<a>
  <b>
    <aaa>val</aaa>
    <bbb></bbb>
  </b>
</a>
```

The stylesheet is very dynamic, i.e. does not rely on the actual element names, but it relies on the *structure* of an XML document.

**Stylesheet ("dynamic")**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*|/*/*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[not(text())]"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[text()]">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the other hand, if the element names are know beforehand and do not change, you can use them in the stylesheet:

**Stylesheet ("static" element names)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/a|b">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="aaa|bbb">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="text()">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise/>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b>
      <aaa>val</aaa>
   </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a empty template for the elements you want to omit, and an identity transform template for the other elements:

```
<xsl:template match="aaa[string-length(text()) = 0]" />
<xsl:template match="bbb[string-length(text()) = 0]" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Instead of checking string length, you could shorten your predicate(s) to `[not(string())]`.

Comment: Yes, or `not(text())` :)

Comment: True but with `string()` you can replace both templates with `<xsl:template match="*[not(string())]"/>`. :-) +1 for a good answer