# How to check XML output from DataContract

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, datacontractserializer

I have inherited some code that is not working properly.  Of course it was working properly as of the last commit but somehow it is not returning good data now.  Historic logs show the data would look like this:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Patron_Key] => 412730
        [x3.32] => 4A
        [x3.1] => 2014-01-08T08:00:00-07:00
        [x3.2] => 2014-01-22T07:59:59-07:00

    )
```

A valid field name is x3.32.  The 'x' is added to the column name on purpose.  However, now the XML is coming out with leading zeroes in the field names, as shown below:

```
    <Patron_Key>363384</Patron_Key>
    <_x0033_.32>BC4S4B</_x0033_.32>
    <_x0033_.1>2013-08-15T08:00:00-06:00</_x0033_.1>
    <_x0033_.2>2014-05-13T07:59:59-06:00</_x0033_.2>
```

So far I have checked that the data coming from the DB via COM+ is valid using PowerShell.  This leads me to think it is either the code or something in IIS.  Whenever I log the data in the code after the COM+ calls and when it is put in a DataTable it looks fine.  The data structure being used has the DataContract attribute and all the class members have the DataMember attribute.  Is there a way I can check the data after it is serialized/deserialized to see if that is where the leading '003' is being added?

Any thoughts on where I might look would be appreciated.  I'm working on getting a new web server spun up just to make sure it has nothing to do with IIS.

**Update**:

It turned out that the issue was because the first character in the column name was a number, and an XML node cannot start with a number.  We found a GitHub comment that got us in the right direction, but I'm also linking to a SO post that describes in more detail the issue.  Oh, and someone introduced some code that wasn't properly detecting numbers in the first character of the column - 5 months ago, so we had to dig through a whole bunch of commits to find the offending change.

[Encoding XML element name beginning with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087108/encoding-xml-element-name-beginning-with-a-number)

Comment: is it somehow thinking the code is a hexidecimal?

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but when I comment out all the places where the 'x' is added to the front of the column name, I get the same result from a soapUI request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two questions:

1. Is there a way I can check the data after it's serialized to see if that's where the leading '003' is being added?
2. Any thoughts on where I might look?

The first one is one I can definitively answer: if you are capable of running your application in debug mode and stepping through the code, you should be able to use the debugger to step through the serialization/deserialization and examine the contents of the variable using a watch. Now, you may have to involve the remote debugger depending on where the code is running, and if you have helper processes you may need to run several instances of Visual Studio with EACH portion of your application running in debug mode to properly track the issue down, but this is what the debugger is for.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Ok.  I have attached to the w3wp process so I can debug the live code during a request.  My first thoughts for breakpoints were looking at the data in about the same place I was logging, so that didn't help.  Should I be setting breakpoints in my own code to catch the serialization/deserialization process?  It appears to me that the serialization is happening by default with the DataContracts as I don't see any calls in my code to System.Xml or System.Runtime.Serialization so I'm not sure how to interrupt that process.

Comment: Deductively, the first place to put the breakpoint would be the call immediately before the error manifests itself. You may also wish to place one at the beginning of the code block in question. If you do indeed see that the value is correct in both places, and things only go wrong upon the serialization to the log, I would further check the value of your variable just AFTER the process and make sure it is STILL correct.

Comment: If you're running into issues with (de)serialization, such issues may not be able to be diagnosed directly, but as you can modify serialization yourself, you should be able to test this indirectly by modifying the serialization behavior and observing the results. Not as good as being able to dive into the process yourself, but still allowing you to get to the bottom of the issue in question.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on serialization.