# XML - Why does the first character of a tag isn't an integer ?

Tags: xml

Just a question of general knowledge...

In the XML specifications, it is defined that a tag can't begin with an integer.

Example

```
<test>Good</test>
<test1>Good</test1>
<1test>Wrong</1test>
<111>Wrong</111>
```

My question is just : why ?

I can understand it forbids "only-integer name", which could be seen as a tag which doesn't describe its content, but why is there the same thing with tag with an integer as first character ?

With some researches, I didn't find anything in : 
- the XML spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-NameStartChar
- the unicode standard spec (which seems to define how to choose a name for a tag...): http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/

Comment: This explains it quite well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087108/encoding-xml-element-name-beginning-with-a-number

Comment: To be specific, this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14621658/171318

Comment: Thank you for your research ! It's interesting to see that performance were considered. If XML was specified today, I'm not sure they will choose to forbid it.