# How to serialize object with numeric element name

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

```
public class UName
{
   [XmlElement("0.23")]
   public string Name1{get;set;}


}
```

when serialize above object then generated as below

```
  <UName><_x0030_.23>value</_x0030_.23></Uname>
```

I need as below as provided attribute number:

```
<UName><0.23>value</0.23></Uname>
```

Comment: You cannot do that.  An XML element name beginning with a number is syntactically invalid.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087108/3744182 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/2519845/3744182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not valid XML.  Element names must start with a **letter or underscore**.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar

Comment: any alternate way to specify type and achive?

Comment: I don't understand the question; please elaborate.

Comment: [XmlEleemnt("0.23"] is specified but serialized as  <_x0030_.23> and I need how specified as <0.23> as element.

Comment: looks, not possible..to have number only in element serialization. Just through, may be specifiying some type, it would allow.

Comment: You cannot do it because it would generate an invalid XML document.  C# is protecting you from yourself.